# Inline-Assembly : prevent HLT from being stopped by windows

Tags: c, gcc, inline-assembly

I try to do `asm("hlt");` on win8 but a windows error window is prompted.

Is there any way to keep HLT running for sometime?

Comment: Even if you could - what do you mean by "keep HLT running"? it's a halt instruction, it's supposed to halt.

Comment: @Leeor windows stops it right away

Answer (score 5):

Unless you are writing a device driver, you can't call HLT.  It is a privileged instruction.

Comment: Even if the OP were writing a device driver, it wouldn't be the place of a device driver to call HLT. The kernel calls its when there is nothing left to do. The device driver is not in a position to know this.

Comment: I'm using it for an experiment, so I need it to be running for ~1 sec.
Will running it on windows xp solve the problem?

Comment: @キューゾリファイ No, even if you're in Win NT 3.1 (as you know it's very old), it prevent you from hlt-ing. It's privileged instruction in x86, so user-space program must not be allowed to use.